# Ant file set using path with spaces in it

Tags: macos, shell, unix, ant

I'm making someone else's ant build work with a source path that contains a space.  Most of it has been basic shell script stuff, adding double-quotes around paths, but this one has me stumped:

(from build.xml):

```
<path id="headers">
    <fileset dir="${source.main.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.h"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

source.main.dir is a path containing spaces.  It's prepended to each of the include file names found by the pattern.  How do I get this to happen with quotes around each one?

In case it matters, I'm running the build from the command line on OS X Lion 10.7.4.

Comment: What are you doing with the path that you need to quote the components? Possible answer might be the pathconvert task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html

Comment: The whole list of fully qualified path names is being passed as an argument to appledoc.  They are already using pathconvert to join them together separated by spaces;  I'll think about whether I can make this work.  I'd need some way to stick a space at the beginning of the first filename and at the end of the last one;  the rest could be done with pathsep, I think.

Comment: Hmm... well, I tried adding extra quotes to the pathsep and also trying to map from the path to the path with quotes around it - both were syntax errors.  Apparently the parser can't handle extra double-quotes, even if they are escaped.  So unless someone knows a way around that, I don't think this will work. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it!  I changed:

```
    <pathconvert pathsep=" " property="doc.files.list" refid="headers" />
```

to

```
    <pathconvert pathsep=" " property="doc.files.list" refid="headers">
        <map from='${source.main.dir}' to='"${source.main.dir}"' />
    </pathconvert>
```

And it seems to be working now.